# Are pr2_ethercat and pr2_ethercat_drivers going to be migrated to use the new ros_control?

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to know if pr2_ethercat and pr2_ethercat_drivers are going to be migrated to use the new ros_control (http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control). And if so, when is it planned to happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107721/are-pr2_ethercat-and-pr2_ethercat_drivers-going-to-be-migrated-to-use-the-new-ros_control?/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late answer.

They will be if someone with a usecase gets the job done. In the end what would need to be done is to create a hardware abstraction for the PR2 that internally leverages the EtherCAT drivers.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0